# How to remove the state field AND make them 'not required' for every country in woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, state, checkout

I found a way to remove the state field 'state' (checkout page in woocommerce) on github
https://gist.github.com/jeherve/a07ccf469025d722ad7016f6953146fd (thank you Jeremy Herve!)

```
    function jeherve_remove_state_field( $fields ) {
    unset( $fields['state'] );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'jeherve_remove_state_field' );
```

My question is: Is it safe to remove the state field or are there already countries set up in woocommerce for which the state field is 'required'?

Do I have to make all state fields for every country 'not required' first?

I'm worrying that after I remove the state field the checkout won't work for some specific countries because they required this field.

I don't have to make the state field $address_fields['state'][required]=false like I would do it for the zip/postcode field, right?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'override_postcode_validation' );
 
function override_postcode_validation( $address_fields ) {
  $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;
  return $address_fields;
}
```

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the state from the checkout form using the same code.

```
function wc_remove_state_field($fields) {

    unset($fields['state']);
    return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'wc_remove_state_field');
```

This will not make any trouble with the checkout process. You don't need to set this for all countries.

1 - Still the zip code will be required to proceed.

2 - Payment gateways that need state as required could not be used to proceed.

Comment: thanks! but that's exactly what I am worrying about... do you know if paypal and stripe as payment gateways need state entered as required?

Comment: Paypal will show: PayPal error (10729): The state in your shipping address is not valid. Please double-check your shipping address and try again.

Comment: Stripe will not have any issues

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'remove_state_validation');

function remove_state_validation($fields) {
    $fields['state']['required'] = false;
    return $fields;
}
```